# C# Castle Windsor xmldatasource configuration in runtime

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle-activerecord

I have problem dynamically/runtime pointing datasource to Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<activerecord isDebug="true" isWeb="false">

  <config>
    <add
        key="connection.provider"
        value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add
        key="connection.connection_string"
        value="Data Source=**database.s3db**;Version=3" />
    <add key="query.substitutions"
         value="true=1;false=0"/>
    <add key="show_sql"
         value="true"/>

        <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect"/>
        <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver"/>

        <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class"
             value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" />


    <!--<add
        key="proxyfactory.factory_class"
        value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle"/>-->

  </config>

</activerecord>
```

So what I want is to change datasource to point to user Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal folder. Is there is anyway to do that ?

Here is my current initialization

```
XmlConfigurationSource source = new XmlConfigurationSource("castle.xml"));

ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, typeof(Account), ... etc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of XmlConfigurationSource use [InPlaceConfigurationSource](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/configref.html#InPlaceConfigurationSource) ([example](http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/LazyTests/Tests.cs?spec=svn371&r=371#25)), expose the really configurable parts via AppSettings / custom config section handler / etc.